# ZF2 Form not showing all the fields value when submit

Tags: forms, zend-framework, input

Create a new module and a form in it but when i submit the form only one field is printed its value all the other are not getting their values:

There are more than 10 fields but only email field is printing its value all the others are empty.

This is what i have in my form:

```
public function __construct($name = null)
 {
     // we want to ignore the name passed
     parent::__construct('company');

     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'id',
         'type' => 'Hidden',
     ));


     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'email',
         'type' => 'Text',
         'options' => array(
             //'label' => 'Strasse',
            // 'placeholder' => 'Email'

         ),
         'attributes' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'Email',
        ),

     ));
     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'firstname',
         'type' => 'Text',
         'options' => array(
             //'label' => 'Strasse',
            // 'placeholder' => 'Email'

         ),
         'attributes' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'Vorname',
        ),
     ));

     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'submit',
         'type' => 'Submit',
         'attributes' => array(
             'value' => 'Go',
             'id' => 'submitbutton',
         ),
     ));
 }
```

I am Getting the values on my modal as follows but it is not showing all the values.

```
 public function saveCompany(Company $company)
 {
     $data = array(
         'firstname'      => $company->firstname,
         'email'        => $company->email,

     );
     echo '<pre>'; print_r($data);
        exit;
```

What Wrong i am donig can you point out and let me know if you need further code to show the here.

[Out Put Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFUPz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed the fields were missed in exchageArray function i updated it and now working fine:

```
public function exchangeArray($data)
 {
     $this->id              = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
     $this->vorname         = (!empty($data['vorname'])) ? $data['vorname'] : null;
     $this->nachname        = (!empty($data['nachname'])) ? $data['nachname'] : null;
     $this->email           = (!empty($data['email'])) ? $data['email'] : null;
     $this->volstangir      = (!empty($data['volstangir'])) ? $data['volstangir'] : null;
     $this->strasse         = (!empty($data['strasse'])) ? $data['strasse'] : null;
     $this->hausnummer      = (!empty($data['hausnummer'])) ? $data['hausnummer'] : null;
     $this->plz             = (!empty($data['plz'])) ? $data['plz'] : null;
     $this->ort             = (!empty($data['ort'])) ? $data['ort'] : null;
     $this->telenummer      = (!empty($data['telenummer'])) ? $data['telenummer'] : null;

 }
```